# Check second char of String in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, masm

I'm using MASM.

I'd like to check the second (and third) character of a String in assembly.

I tried this:

```
; String is in DWORD operandA
mov eax, OFFSET operandA+1
cmp eax, '!'
je Fact
```

This doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd need to dereference the pointer to get the actual character:

```
mov eax, OFFSET operandA+1
mov cl,byte ptr [eax]
cmp cl,'!'
```

or

```
mov eax, OFFSET operandA
mov cl,byte ptr [eax + 1]
cmp cl,'!'
```

this preserves eax so you can compare the second char using:

```
inc eax
mov cl,byte ptr [eax]
cmp cl,'?'
```

or

```
mov cl,byte ptr [eax + 2]
cmp cl,'?'
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken your first and second example are not equivalent? Setting eax to operandA+1 will read the pointer value from the wrong address.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde: they will read from the same address so long as `operandA` elements have a size of 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

Why the unneeded movs?  You could do this:

```
;szSomeString    BYTE    "?!@ABC", 0
    mov     eax, offset szSomeString
    xor     ebx, ebx
    inc     ebx
    cmp     byte ptr [eax + 1 * ebx], "!"
    je      Yes
    jmp     @F

    ; Second char no match
Yes:
    ; Second char match
```

or

```
    mov     eax, offset szSomeString
    inc     eax
    cmp     byte ptr [eax], "!"
    je      Yes
    jmp     @F
```

Comment: Well, you could even do `mov eax, offset szSomeString`+`cmp byte ptr [eax+1], "!"` or `cmp byte ptr [szSomeString+1], "!"`